# Entity Framework Update related entity

Tags: entity-framework

I get an error message while trying to update related entity.

When create new one is OK.

The error message say :

*A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property values that define the 
referential constraints are not consistent between principal and dependent objects in the relationship.*

**Please review my codes, and advice me what I am doing wrong.**

First of all, DB is Mysql MyISAM.

Entity Class

```
[Table("note")]
public class Note
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Content is required")]
    [DisplayName("Note")]
    public string content { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "User ID is required")]
    [DisplayName("User ID")]
    public string userId {get; set;}
    public Boolean isPrivate { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Attach File")]
    public virtual ICollection<AttachedFile> AttachedFiles { get; set; }

}

[Table("attachedfile")]
public class AttachedFile
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int noteId { get; set; }
    public string fileName { get; set; }
}
```

Controller,

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Note note, HttpPostedFileBase attFile)
{
    try
    {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        updateAttachFile(note, attFile);
        if (note.id > 0)
        {
        unitOfWork.NoteRepository.UpdateNote(note);
        }
        else
        {
        unitOfWork.NoteRepository.InsertNote(note);
        }

        unitOfWork.Save();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    }catch(DataException){
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again please");
    }

    var notes = unitOfWork.NoteRepository.GetNotes();
    return View(new NoteViewModel() { noteList = notes.ToList(), note = new Note() });
}

private void updateAttachFile(Note note,HttpPostedFileBase attFile)
{
    if (attFile == null) return;

    List<AttachedFile> list;
    if (note.id > 0)
    {
    list = unitOfWork.AttachedFileRepository.Get(filter: q => q.noteId.Equals(note.id)).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
    list = new List<AttachedFile>();
    }

    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(attFile.FileName);
    fileName = fileName.Replace(" ", "");
    fileName = Regex.Replace(fileName, @"\s|\$|\#\%", "");
    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_data/uploads"), fileName);
    attFile.SaveAs(path);

    list.Add(new AttachedFile
    {
    fileName = fileName
    });

    note.AttachedFiles = list;
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting the state of `note` to `Modified` EF will attach the related entities, especially the newly created `AttachedFile`, to the context as well, but in state `Unchanged`. You haven't set the correct foreign key property value though (which is necessary if the entity is not in state `Added`). Doing this would remove the exception:

```
list.Add(new AttachedFile
{
    noteId = note.id,
    fileName = fileName
});
```

But your new `AttachedFile` won't be added to your database because it's not in `Added` state.

I would expect that is works if you call `updateAttachFile` after Update/Insert...

```
if (note.id > 0)
    unitOfWork.NoteRepository.UpdateNote(note);
else
    unitOfWork.NoteRepository.InsertNote(note);
updateAttachFile(note, attFile);
unitOfWork.Save();
```

...because change detection happening in `SaveChanges` will recognize the new entity and put it into `Added` state automatically.

As a side note: I don't know why you load the existing AttachedFiles with `unitOfWork.AttachedFileRepository.Get...`. It should work in my opinion with an empty `list` for both cases Update and Insert.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understand how EF works. I loaded existed data because I thought it will replace with existed data too.^^ May I ask one more question please?, How EF knows Note.id related with AttachedFile.noteId? I didn't define in anywhere and also it is MYISAM that is not available define FK.

Comment: For example, I add noteNo field into AttachedFile table and add noteNo variable into entity class too. And I run the application, it work fine, EF didn't confused at all :). Now what if I want I change FK to noteNo not noteID, how should I do this?

Comment: @Expertwannabe: About your first comment: EF knows it because it applies certain naming conventions to infer a mapping. In this case: It sees the `AttachedFiles` collection that refers to the `AttachedFile` class. Then it looks if in this class is a property with name "Class name of Note + Property Name of PK" (=`NoteId`, capital and small letters don't matter). And yes, there is one: `noteId`. Then it assumes that this must be the foreign key property. If you would give it another name like `MySpecialId` it wouldn't find an FK property and your exception would not occur.

Comment: @Expertwannabe: About your second comment: If `noteId` doesn't represent a foreign key, then yes, it is the easiest solution to rename it.

Comment: @Expertwannabe: I meant to rename the property `noteId` to `noteNo` or so? Don't you want this? I don't understand the MyIsam thing, why there is no definition of a FK possible. Maybe ask a new question about this problem.